# Set efivar SystemAudiVolume in Linux from recovery mode in MacOs

Tags: arch-linux, macos

I tried getting rid of the anoying startup sound in linux like described in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536436/linux-modify-an-efi-var-with-efivar?newreg=0afbcf00f19a4e8793d1c47cc0c07cc3) from the MacOs recovery mode.

After setting `nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00` I rebooted the system and logged into my linux environment but the `efivar` command revealed that the value has not changed.

How can I persist the setting in linux after rebooting from the recovery mode in MacOs?

I have a Macbook Pro 2013.